# self referencing in data bindings

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

Let's say there is a Combobox:

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Path=ListOfItems}">
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox Tag="{Binding Path=this}"
        Content="{Binding Path=AProperty}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>                                       
</ComboBox>
```

Now what I want is that the *Content* property of ComboBox is bounded to the according *list elements's* property *AProperty* (which works fine) and the *Tag* property is bounded to the *list element* itself, which does not work. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To bind to the current data context you can use `.`:

```
<CheckBox Tag="{Binding Path=.}"
```

Or, effectively the same, simply omit the path altogether:

```
<CheckBox Tag="{Binding}"
```